# Truncate coordinates (LonLat) to decimal precision

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinates, latitude-longitude, decimal-points

For example if coordinates are `17.12345678, -82.12345678`, and I want to convert them to 3 decimal digits.

Expected result: `17.123, -82.123`

Is there any API in OpenLayers 2 to truncate coordinates (LonLat) to decimal precision?

Comment: Your meaning is unclear. Do you really want to snap vertices to the nearest degree?

Comment: if coordinates are 17.12345678, -82.12345678, 
For eg. If I want to convert them to 3 decimal digits,
Expected result: 17.123, -82.123
Is there any api in openLayers 2 to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the LonLat object you could define your own method

```
OpenLayers.LonLat.prototype.truncate = function(digits) {
    var pow = Math.pow(10, digits);
    return new OpenLayers.LonLat(Math.round(this.lon * pow)/pow, Math.round(this.lat * pow)/pow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I presume there is no built-in api in OpenLayers 2